# set status command resetting after restart (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i have this code that changes the status of my bot when you type `!status <status>` and it works fine, but when i restart my bot, the status resets to whatever i have defined it as in the start, is there any way to fix this?

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const text = args.join(' ');


    if (command === 'status') { 
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`Please tell the bot what to say, ${message.author}`);
        }
    
        client.user.setActivity(text, { //write msg here
            type: "WATCHING", //LISTENING or PLAYING
            name: "itt"
        });
        message.channel.send('Changed status to ' + text)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, variables exist only while the script is running, and then are deleted, until you run the script again. One way to store values while the script is not running, is with a `.json` file. In the directory that your app or index.js file is, you could add a `status.json` file. Here is an example of how it works.

```js
const fs = require("fs")
var status = require("./status.json")

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(status.status, { //write msg here
        type: "WATCHING", //LISTENING or PLAYING
        name: "itt"
    });
})

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const text = args.join(' ');


    if (command === 'status') { 
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`Please tell the bot what to say, ${message.author}`);
        }
    
        client.user.setActivity(text, { //write msg here
            type: "WATCHING", //LISTENING or PLAYING
            name: "itt"
        });
        message.channel.send('Changed status to ' + text)
        status.status = text
        fs.writeFile("./status.json", JSON.stringify(status, null, 4), "utf8", err => {
            if (err) throw err
        })
    }
});
```

`status.json:`

```
{
     "status": "bot status"
}
```

Comment: i think i understand this, but could you possibly advise onto how to fit this into my specific use case?

Comment: @cookieclock i updated it to be specific to what you need